# How do I dynamically set the field I wish to update in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to update a specific element of a highly nested array object but I can't dynamically choose the field any thoughts? I basically need to run the following in a for loop.

```
collection.updateOne({ _id: "MY_ID"},[
  {
    $set: {
       `array1.${i}.array2.${j}.id_field` : new UUID()
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: I know you self-answered but for clarity, could you edit both the question with where `i` and `j` are coming from *and* also edit your self-answer to explain what wrapping the string in brackets does to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, all I have to do is wrap the string in brackets [].

```
collection.updateOne({ _id: "MY_ID"},[
  {
    $set: {
       [`array1.${i}.array2.${j}.id_field`] : new UUID()
    },
  },
])
```